# ternary in postlude?

Tags: krl

Can I do ternary in the postlude(s) the same way that I do them int he prelude? In other words have it fire off different calls depending on the say something was evaluated in the prelude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can include a [guard condition](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Postlude) on a postlude expression. This works for both explicit event raising and persistant variable modification. The expression following `if` can be any valid expression, including functions.

Example:

```
fired {
  raise explicit event "foo" if cheese == 5;
}
```